# How to set API access token to environment variable in python for Smartsheet API?

Tags: python, api, environment-variables, token, smartsheet-api

I ran the repository for python-read-write-sheet by smartsheet sample in VisualStudioCode and had came across a message on the terminal. I had installed the SDK required in the virtual environment (.venv) before running the code.

In Line 49, the initialize client uses the API token in the environment variable "SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN" smart = smartsheet.Smartsheet()

However, the terminal raised the error on the exact message where ValueError('Access Token must be set in the environment ' ValueError: Access Token must be set in the environment or passed to smartsheet.Smartsheet() as a parameter.

The python script which I am using is python-read-write-sheet.py https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/python-read-write-sheet

I had read the repository and I think that generating the access token could be the solution, I believe this is stated under the "Configure" section in the repo. https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/python-read-write-sheet

Answer (score 1):

The access token is what tells Smartsheet what user (account) to use to execute the API calls. Any time you're writing code that calls an API (which requires authentication), that code needs to specify the access token corresponding to the user (account) that should be used to run the API calls.

First, if you haven't already done so, you'll need to login to Smartsheet (https://app.smartsheet.com) using the login credentials of the account you want to use for API calls and generate an *Access Token* (i.e., *API Key*). You can find instructions for how to do this here: https://help.smartsheet.com/articles/2482389-generate-API-key.

Next, once you have generated an access token via the Smartsheet app, you need to store it in the `SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN` environment variable in your code. To do this:

- Add this import statement to the top of your code:

```
import os
```

- Add the following code to set the `SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN` environment variable to your access token. (In the following example code, replace `abc123` with your access token value.) **NOTE:** This line of code needs to be place before the line of code that attempts to read the value of that environment variable (`smart = smartsheet.Smartsheet()`).

```
# Specify access token
os.environ['SMARTSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN'] = 'abc123'
```